# Limit of number of service keys for IBM Cloud Object Storage

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud-storage

For a use case, we will have to generate 100's of 1000's of service keys for IBM Cloud object storage service. The service keys will be generated at different instants of time and will typically expire in couple of hours, but at any point of time there would be > 100000 service keys for IBM COS. Just wanted to check if there are any constraints defined by Cloud foundry or its specific implementation in IBM Cloud which would be need to factored in this solution. Appreciate response. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Foundry has quotas on the org and space level that can be configured to limited the maximum number of service keys that can exist at any time.

This particular quota is not exposed in the `cf quotas` and related commands. You can use `cf curl` with the related CC APIs (http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/280/organization_quota_definitions/retrieve_a_particular_organization_quota_definition.html, http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/280/space_quota_definitions/retrieve_a_particular_space_quota_definition.html).